# How to use the function "first" and "last" in SAS

Tags: function, sas

I'd like to get the variable FLG using first and last function in SAS. The data is sorted by No. The following my program is wrong. How do I get it? Please give me some advice.

```
data test;
 input SUBJID NO AVAL;
 cards;
 1 1 0
 1 2 0
 1 3 0
 1 4 1
 1 5 1
 1 6 1
 1 7 0
 1 8 0
 ;
 run;

proc sort data = test; by SUBJID NO AVAL; run;
data test2;
 set test;
 by SUBJID NO AVAL;
 if first.AVAL then FLG = 1;
 if last.AVAL  then FLG = 2;
 run;

/*
I want the dataset.

SUBJID NO AVAL FLG
1       1   0   1
1       2   0   
1       3   0   2
1       4   1   1
1       5   1   
1       6   1   2
1       7   0   1
1       8   0   2
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to SORT the data by SUBJECT and NO.  But tell the DATA step to group it by SUBJECT and AVAL.  You will need the NOTSORTED keyword because it is not sorted by AVAL value.

```
data test2;
  set test;
  by SUBJID AVAL notsorted;
  if first.AVAL then FLG = 1;
  if last.AVAL  then FLG = 2;
run;
```

PS The FIRST. and LAST. flag variables are not functions.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I got it. Very useful.